# Panda array from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like this

```
[{"Key":[val1,val2,...]}, {"Key2":[val1,val2,...]}, ...]
```

I would like to convert this to a csv format where the keys are column headers, and he values form the column values

To do this I had intended to use a `pandas` dataframe (which exports to csv readily), but I can't work out how to get my values into the data frame.

I've tried `myPanda = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)` but alas, to no avail.

Comment: Is the only reason you are using `pandas` to export to csv?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming your keys are unique, otherwise this wouldn't make much sense.

**Option 1**

1. merge your dictionaries to a single dict
2. pass the dict to `pd.DataFrame`
3. save as CSV using `df.to_csv`

```
dct = [{...}, {...}, ...]

r = {}
for d in dct:
    r.update(d)

pd.DataFrame(r).to_csv('file.csv')
```

---

**Option 2**
Using [`cytoolz`](https://github.com/pytoolz/cytoolz), there's another possibility for dictionary merging -

```
from cytoolz.dicttoolz import merge
df = pd.DataFrame(merge(*dct))
```

---

**Option 3**
Create separate dataframes and concatenate them -

```
df = pd.concat(list(map(pd.DataFrame, dct)), axis=1)
```

This option works even if your lists are uneven.

Credit to piRSquared for the last two solutions!.

Comment: I thought of this `pd.DataFrame([list(*i.values()) for i in di],columns = [list(i.keys())[0] for i in di])` But your approach is really neat.

Comment: @Bharath Woah... yeah. That does seem overly complicated!

Comment: If you import `merge` from `cytoolz.dicttoolz` you can do this `pd.DataFrame(merge(*dct))`

Comment: @Bharath 's solution revisited `pd.DataFrame({k: v for d in dct for k, v in d.items()})`

Comment: Last one I swear... `pd.concat(list(map(pd.DataFrame, dct)), axis=1)`

Comment: Last one would take care of the caveat too ;)